# Dialogflow slack integration is broken?

Tags: dialogflow-es, slack-api, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

Im trying to publish a bot in my slack workspace, but seems thatdialogflow  integration with slack is broken :/

I run some tests and find out that app in slack is sending the payload to dialogflow, but this dont respond back at all.

I follow all the steps on the tutorial but the documentation of dialogflow seems out of date.

Anyone knows if the best way to integrate both is trought dialogflow integration or have other way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Slack has released a new OAuth workflow. You can check this documentation for more information: https://api.slack.com/authentication/quickstart.

With that, dialogFlow introduce a new OAuth and Events Request URL to support Slack’s new workflow. Their documentation is out of date in this answer time.

If you haven’t upgraded your Slack app, just follow instructions in public documentation at https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/integrations/slack.

Otherwise, follow these steps in integrating your agent with an upgraded Slack app or a newly created Slack app.

1. Go to Slack > Basic Information tab and copy the Client ID, Client Secret and Verification Token.
2. Go to the Dialogflow Integrations page, enable Slack integration, paste the credentials accordingly and click START.
3. Copy the OAuth and Events Request URL.
4. Go to Slack > OAuth & Permissions tab and update the Redirect URLs with the OAuth URL provided in Dialogflow. However, replace v1 with v2. It should look like this: [https://dialogflow.cloud.google.com/v2/integrations/slack/auth/{agent-id}](https://dialogflow.cloud.google.com/v2/integrations/slack/auth/%7Bagent-id%7D).
5. On the same page, add the following OAuth Scopes in the Bot Token Scopes section.

- app_mentions:read
- calls:read
- calls:write
- channels:history
- channels:read
- chat:write
- groups:history
- im:history
- im:read
- im:write
- team:read

6. Go to the Event Subscriptions tab and update the Request URL with the Events Request URL provided in Dialogflow.
7. Under the Subscribe to Bot Events section, click on the Add Bot User Event button and add the following events as described here https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/integrations/slack#enable_event_subscriptions.
8. Once you've added the events, click the Save Changes button at the bottom of the screen.
9. Go to the Install App tab and click Install App to Workspace.
10. Go to the Manage Distribution tab and click Add to Slack.

This should work until then dont upgrade de docs :)